# Is there a way to remote update files on a usb stick?

Tags: storage, remote-access

I have looked on the internet but unable to find a solution that would fit my requirements and was wondering if someone could either direct me to a solution or guide me towards making a customized solution.

So here is the scenario, we have a machine that runs a screensaver. Occasionally we are required to update the file on the machine, the trouble is that a person has to go there physically to update the usb. is there a way to allow remote access (via the internet) to a usb storage device to update files?

Comment: You can share the USB device and connect to is over network, but I do not know your environmet for more specific answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "a machine that runs a screensaver"? And the part about usb is confusing too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the operating-system and network-conditions, but you should be able to connect to the machine via SSH and remotely access the USB-drive.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/50104/how-do-i-access-an-external-drive-mounted-on-a-machine-on-my-own-network

I hope that's enough to throw at Google combined with your specific environment.

Comment: Thanks, am going to give that a shot.